# Laravel 4: Sitewide Printing and Excel Export

Tags: laravel-4

I have a Laravel site with about 30-or-so sub-systems. Most of these systems pull in data from a MySQL database. When a users searches for a specific set of records, I'd like them to be able to export those records to Excel and/or PDF. Basically at the top of each search results page, I'd have a button/link/whatever for 'Export to PDF' and one for 'Export to Spreadsheet'.

My problem is I have really never had to design something this large before and I don't have a really good idea of where to start. Should I just make this functionality in each system's controller or should I write base code and plop it somewhere else within my site structure?

**Example of a Sub-System 'A'**

Subsystem 'A' allows librarians to create, edit, delete and search records of all of the instruction sessions they have led.

**Example of a Subsystem 'B'**

Subsystem 'B' allows administrators to create, edit, delete, and search records of all donations that have been made to a department.

--

Comment: Your question is kind of generic and it's hard to give good advice without a clear picture of your application structure (especially since you mentioned it's large and possibly complex).

Comment: Yeah I really have no clue how to even begin to describe the layout of the system virtually. I don't even have any of the subsystems built yet. Maybe it will become more obvious when I start adding more components.

Comment: Seems like you have some restful resources there. So if you have an `index` action that lists the records, you can add a `export` controller action for exporting the records. In that action you'll perhaps call a repository method that is responsible for converting the resource into the specific format (pdf, xls, etc) and return it for download.